# Jsoup is escaping content of iframe

Tags: java, html, parsing, iframe, jsoup

I have this in source html that I want to parse

```
<div>
<iframe><script>alert('hello')</script></iframe>
</div>
```

When I parse using Jsoup and print the body html I get this.

```
<div>
<iframe>&lt;script&gt;alert('hello')&lt;/script&gt;</iframe>
</div>
```

I don't want Jsoup to convert the content inside iframe. How can I do this?. Sample code

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

Comment: hi, did you resolve this?

Comment: Nope I did not @quento

Answer (score 2):

You can use the unescapeEntities(String,boolean) method of jsoup parser :

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);            
 System.out.println(org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(doc.body().html(), true));
```

Comment: Well this unescapes everything, not only what's inside <iframe>. So, unfortunately, this ain't working for me.