# Write a HTML tag as a String in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have an element like below;

```
<p> I am lost </p>`
```

I need to highlight "am" like below;

```
<p> I <mark style="background-color:#FFFF00;">am</mark> lost </p>
```

My code is like this.

```
String newText = "I <mark style=\"background-color:#FFFF00;\">am</mark> lost"; 
element.text(newText);
```

But when I print the element it looks like this.

```
<p>I &lt;mark style="background-color:#FF0000;"&gt;am&lt;/mark&gt; lost</p>
```

Are there any ways to force "<" and ">" characters to elements using Jsoup?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I had simular problem and solve it using `var = "<&zwj;div>I am lost</div&zwj;>"`. `&zwj;` is the Unicode Character to [Zero Width Joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner)

Comment: @MatheusCuba Thank you. But it did not work :-)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [How to prevent jsoup converting special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186195/how-to-prevent-jsoup-converting-special-characters) which is a duplicate of [Jsoup is escaping content of iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41162438/42962).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `element.text(newText)` you should use `element.html(newText)`